# IAP restore doesn't work

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, baker-framework

I have problem with IAP. In sandbox mode application work fine, but when app was reviewed in iTunes connection restoring does not working.

When use real apple id, method `(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray*)transactions`
never has been called.
My app using "baker framework"

Comment: check if you are gtting SKProducts

Comment: @Saurabh Prajapati Mehod `- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
     didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response` return all SKProducts

Comment: check for delegate??

Comment: I added `SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver` and '[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:purchasesManager];' [baker framework h file](https://github.com/bakerframework/baker/blob/master/BakerShelf/BKRPurchasesManager.h) [baker framework .m file](https://github.com/bakerframework/baker/blob/master/BakerShelf/BKRPurchasesManager.m)

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati did apple pass aplication with development provisioning profile?